# Unable to understand behaviour of node.childrens

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

```
<tr>
<th style="text-align: center; background: #f08080;" colspan="3">خدیجہ مستور</th>
</tr>
```

when iterating using htmlagilityPack using node.children (recursively) i am getting this output:

```
tr
 |->#text:
 |->th
  |-->#text: خدیجہ مستور
 |->#text:
```

using node.childrens gives 3 childrens of tr tag : #text,th,#text i just want to iterate such that only direct childrens iterated first and then childrens of children. i am confused to get #text two times as child of tr from where these two #text are coming??? or what is this behavious can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is as expected.

There are two, empty text nodes in the markup - before the `<th>` and after it - the line breaks count.

You can exclude empty text nodes in your output.

Comment: how to exclude those empty nodes when working in C# any method or any prototype?

Comment: i did use node.text!=null && node.text!=""   after conversion of htmlNode to HtmlTextNode but i faild :(

Comment: @samRobort - `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(node.text)` should work better.